# Не работает mysql запрос в php

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

В таблице 2 колонки: имя и пароль, необходимо проверить, есть ли такие данные в таблице и соответствует ли имя паролю. Использую myphpadmin. Собственно код:

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","admin","ляляля");
mysql_select_db("mybd",$db);
$name = $_POST["name"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];
$res = mysql_query("SELECT name, pass FROM maintable WHERE name=$name, pass=$pass", $db);
if ($res){
    $arr = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    echo "вы вошли в систему";
}
else echo "$name, вас нету в базе!<br>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <?php
   $ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    mysql_connect ("localhost", "log", "pass") or die("Сервер mysql выключен, свяжитесь с администрацией");
    mysql_select_db ($db) or die (mysql_error());
     $log = !empty($_POST['login']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']) : null;
     $pas = !empty($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;
     $query = "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `login` = '$log'";
   $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

  if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
       if ($row['password'] === $pas) {
          $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['id'];
           $_SESSION['login'] = $row['login'];
           $_SESSION['passwd'] = $row['password'];
           $_SESSION['access'] = $row['accessLevel'];
           echo 'ВЫ ВОШЛИ В СИСТЕМУ';
           //обновим последний IP юзера
          mysql_query("UPDATE accounts SET lastIP ='$ip' WHERE login = '$log' AND password = '$pas'") or die (mysql_error());
          } else {
          echo "<font color=red>Неправильный пороль</font>";
     }
  } else {
     echo "<font color=red>Не указано Имя</font>";
}
?>
```

как то так, допилишь под себя)) тут хотябы проверка есть данных на входе)

а то можно и инъекцию получить)

Answer (score 3):

Если вы всё же хотите понять свою проблему, тио внимательней посмотрите на эту строку:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT name, pass FROM maintable WHERE name=$name, pass=$pass", $db);
```

name=$name**,** pass=$pass

вместо "," должно быть "AND" и переменные должны находится в кавычках. В итоге должно выйти чтото типа:

... name='$name' **AND** pass='$pass' ...

Answer (score 0):

Думаю это поможет:

```
$name = mysql_escape_string($_POST["name"]);
$pass = mysql_escape_string($_POST["pass"]);
$res = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `pass` FROM maintable WHERE `name`='$name', `pass`='$pass'", $db);
```